# Page Counter with Analytics where data is stored in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, analytics, pageviews

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6901524/102067), I wish to keep track of the number of page views.  However, unlike that question, I would like to use MySQL to store the data.  How do you propose that I set up my table to efficiently sore the data related to that specific page?

I would also like to apply some "intelligence" to the page counter.  How can I keep track of the unique pageviews (similar to SO) in addition to the overall pageviews?  How should I modify the table from above to suit these changes?

Additionally, could I use this information to track advertisement "views"?  If so, how? If not, then I'll gladly post that as another question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the structure of the table you would record every-single-hit.

```
id | date | ip | user-cookie | agent
```

And then for performance reasons you could have another table that would be updated by a cron-job.

```
id | unique-hits
```

**How to define a unique user?**
This is [a bit of a grey area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_user) where your own levels of paranoia kick in. A unique user can be a registered user and that should count as really one hit per user. You can follow the flawed one ip / one user. You can mix and match IP's and user agent's to try and better debunk unique users. Time can also be put into the mix, say every IP after x days will count as a new user.

**Do you have a digital fingeprint?**
Flash version, and other odities may cause your browser to be "different" from all other browsers creating a more *unique* view of yourself. Hit the great https://panopticlick.eff.org/ for a preview of what you may look like to a server.

**How does Google Analytics does it?**
Aparenttly they go [cookie all the way](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html).

Comment: What are your thoughts about my 'advertisement views' portion of the question?

Comment: @ServAce85 say you want to track users from campaign one, you can link users to your site http://example.com/?ad=campaign1 and track the `ad` part of the field. That's how the majority of sites work.